# Set element i,j in matrix to i*j in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I want to generate a matrix in which the i,j element equals i*j, where i != j.

e.g.

```
0 2 3
2 0 6
3 6 0
```

So far I've figured out that I can access the non-diagonal elements with this index matrix

```
idx = 1 - eye(3)
```

but I haven't figured out how to incorporate the indices of the matrix cells into the computation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm considering the general case (matrix not necessarily square). Let

```
m = 4; %// number of rows
n = 3; %// number of columns
```

There are quite a few approaches:

1. Using `ndgrid`:

   ```
   [ii jj] = ndgrid(1:m,1:n);
   result = (ii.*jj).*(ii~=jj);
   ```
2. Using `bsxfun`:

   ```
   result = bsxfun(@times, (1:m).',1:n) .* bsxfun(@ne, (1:m).',1:n);
   ```
3. Using `repmat` and `cumsum`:

   ```
   result = cumsum(repmat(1:n,m,1));
   result(1:m+1:m^2) = 0;
   ```
4. Using matrix multiplication (added by @GastónBengolea):

   ```
   result = (1:m).'*(1:n).*~eye(m,n);
   ```

Answer (score 7):

How about

```
N=3;  %size of matrix
A=[1:N]'*[1:N]-diag([1:N].^2)
```

Comment: Good just for a square matrix.

Comment: +1 in my eyes most elegant solution. I would even use: `[1:N]'*[1:N].*~diag([1:N])`

Answer (score 4):

One more trick is to abuse the [`kron`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) function:

```
>> m = 4;
>> n = 3;
>> a = kron((1:m)', 1:n);
>> a(eye(m, n, 'logical')) = 0

a =

    0    2    3
    2    0    6
    3    6    0
    4    8   12
```

Comment: +1 for `kron`. Hey, why is `a(1:m+1:end) = 0` silly? ;-) Anyway, it may not work if n>m (but I don't think that's why you say it). You need `a(1:m+1:min(m,n)^2)=0`

Comment: And you're right, `m^2` suffices. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

```
for i=1:3
    for j=1:3
        if i==j
           A(i,j)=0;
        else
           A(i,j)=i*j;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: You should preallocate `A=zeros(3);` to make code much faster (and then you can remove first branch of `if`). Also, `for` loops are [may not be the best choice](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) in Matlab

Comment: I agree with @LuisMendo. Also, this piece of code is not working (`A[i j]` is nothing. I guess you mean `A[i,j]`), so the answer is not really a complete answer.

Comment: Anything that is not direct matrix operations, post-processing, or toolboxes are not the best choice in MatLab. But unless he's planning to create very big matrix, this will do =D

Comment: @user3277173 There are other choices that work well in Matlab: `bsxfun` and `ndgrid` for example

Comment: You are right, sebas. My MatLab skills are really rusty. @Luis Mendo,  bsxfun and ndgrid are just examples of setting up matrix that are good enough to be directly operated. And for that, yes, way more efficient than for loop

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster: "Readable" is in the eye of the beholder :) I prefer `(1:m)'*(1:n)`